# Unable to capture images inserted to Google Image search results page with MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

[image]

I'm trying to create chrome extension that blocks (or blurs) all images on the web pages (including dynamically generated). Some of DOM insertions are being successfully observed, but after a little scrolling, images stop being caught.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationList => {
  mutationList.forEach(mutation => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
        if (node.tagName === 'IMG') {
          node.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
          console.log(node);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
  attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true
});
```

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "persistent": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: addedNodes doesn't list **every** added node, it may be just one parent element with all the images inside, so you must also use querySelectorAll on each node if node.firstElementChild is true.